# convert from scriptlet to JSF managed bean problem

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, scriptlet

I am trying to convert this [scriptlet code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/CreatingClientServerApplications.htm) to JSF class.

The view code

```
<f:view>
<h:form binding="#{jsfSocketClient.form}">
    <h:outputText binding="#{jsfSocketClient.text}"/>

</h:form>
</f:view>
```

and the java code

```
private HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
private HtmlOutputText text = new HtmlOutputText();

public HtmlForm getForm() 
{
    System.out.println("instance:  "+FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseWriter());
    ResponseWriter writer = (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getResponseWriter();  
    try{

        int character;
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8765);

        InputStream inSocket = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outSocket = socket.getOutputStream();

        String str = "Hello!\n";
        byte buffer[] = str.getBytes();
        outSocket.write(buffer);
        char characters = 0;
        while ((character = inSocket.read()) != -1) {
            text.setValue((char)character);
            //writer.write((char)character);
            //characters += (char)character;
        }
        //text.setValue(characters);
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
                {
                    socket.close();
                }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        text.setValue("You must first start the server application (YourServer.java) at the command prompt.");          
    }
    return form;
}
```

When I run scriptlet code, I am getting the answer as 
"The server got this: Hello! "

When I run the JSF code I am not getting this reply.  Please correct my mistake

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you _run_ the jsf code.. ?

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: @tomas some unknown character like this ঠ

Comment: @Bozho Sorry I couldn't get you

Comment: @mvg: this is caused because your code for the InputStream processing is wrong. You should not cast directly every byte to a char, as some special chars can be two bytes long. Also, you are overriding the text value for every byte, so at the end, text only contains one byte. Check @morja answer and it's InputStream processing.

Comment: @Bozho  I just started YourServer.Java in console from Eclipse and then started this JSF page in Eclipse.

Comment: @Tomas You spotted the correct problem. I did not handle the inputstream correctly. Apart from trying morja's code, I modified the code, provided in the question.  Using Stringbuffer I appended the input value and outside the loop I set the Stringbuffer to the HTMLOutputText.  This also worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I correct my answer. The problem is the processing of the input stream. Here is the fixed code:

```
    String response = "";
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8765);

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        OutputStream outSocket = socket.getOutputStream();

        String str = "Hello!\n";
        byte buffer[] = str.getBytes();
        outSocket.write(buffer);

        CharArrayWriter result = new CharArrayWriter();
        char[] buf = new char[4096];
        int charsRead = 0;
        while ((charsRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
            result.write(buf, 0, charsRead);
        }
        response = result.toString();

        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "You must first start the server application (YourServer.java) at the command prompt.";
    }
    text.setValue(response);
```

Comment: I think that the main problem in fact was the input socket processing, in which he was setting for every byte the value field, with a direct conversion to a character. @morja code process the InputStream in a correct way, so my upvote for this answer.

Comment: True. I fixed the code (buffer/buf) mistake, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @morja The error comes as "The method read(byte[]) in the type InputStream is not applicable for the arguments (char[])" when I use your updated code.  I debugged your previous code and it receiving some input from the server, but only empty string returns as output

Comment: @mvg Yes, sorry, there was another thing I missed in the code, I changed it to use a Reader.

Comment: @morja binding is not the problem